# Getting rotation from matrix, OpenMaya

Tags: matrix, 3d, maya, pymel, maya-api

I'm working with OpenMaya and I need to get the Euler rotation from a matrix but i'm getting an error while I launch this simple code:

code:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.cmds as mc
crcl=mc.circle()
matrx=(OpenMaya.MMatrix(mc.xform(crcl,q=1,m=1)))
tMat = OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix(matrx)
eulerRotation = tMat.rotation(asQuaternion=False)
```

error

`Error: in method 'new_MMatrix', argument 1 of type 'float const [4][4]'`

the problem is the `OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix(matrx)`, looks like is not accepting my matrix.
Any help?

[MTransformationMatrix documentation](https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/api/class_m_transformation_matrix.html)

I'm sure is a simple fix that I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the matrix is to avoid going through the MEL command and use the `OpenMaya` API directly.

```py
import math
# I'm Using `maya.api.OpenMaya` here since I'm testing on Maya 2019.
# Change according to your version.
import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.cmds as mc

crcl = mc.circle()
mc.rotate(45.0, 10.0, 5.0, crcl)

# Add the circle to the selection so we can retrieve its `MObject`.
selection = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
selection.add(crcl[0])

# Get the circle `MObject` and create a `MFnDagNode` from it.
obj = selection.getDependNode(0)
dagNode = OpenMaya.MFnDagNode(obj)

matrix = dagNode.transformationMatrix()
tMat = OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix(matrix)
eulerRotation = tMat.rotation(asQuaternion=False)

# This should print the following (only differences would potentially be in
# floating point accuracy):
# [45.0, 10.0, 5.0]
print(map(math.degrees, eulerRotation))
```

Comment: That was very helpful!
thanks, I manage to find the error on the code, I was using  `maya.OpenMaya` instead of  `maya.api.OpenMaya` in fact if you change just that part the code work!